# TYPO3: Map fe_users to a parent record of fe_users

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

In a custom extension I extend the fe_users table with a field "manager". This fields holds the boss of the user.

Now I want to save the value of the field "tx_igldapssoauth_dn" (which comes from [ext:ig_ldap_sso_auth](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ig_ldap_sso_auth/)) of the parent record in the field "manager" and not the "uid".

My model looks like that:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model;

class FrontendUser extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser
{

    /**
     * DN of the users manager
     *
     * @var Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\FrontendUser
     * @lazy
     */
    protected $manager = '';

    /**
     * Returns the manager
     *
     * @return Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\FrontendUser $manager
     */
    public function getManager()
    {
        return $this->manager;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the manager
     *
     * @param Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\FrontendUser $manager
     * @return void
     */
    public function setManager($manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }
}
```

TCA:

```
'manager' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_feusers_users.manager',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'foreign_table' => 'fe_users',
    ],
],
```

This works fine and returns me the parent record. BUT this saves the "uid" of the parent record in the column "manager" and not the value of the field "tx_igldapssoauth_dn".

So what needs to be configured or changed in order to save the value of "tx_igldapssoauth_dn" in the field "manager" and not the "uid"?

**EDIT (more detailed info)**

The value for the field "manager" is filled by the LDAP (it is the DN of the parent user, the boss) as well as "tx_igldapssoauth_dn", which is the DN of the user itself. So "tx_igldapssoauth_dn" is a unique value and can be compared with the uid of the entry.

My problem is not saving the needed value to the field "manager" but connecting the field "manger" with the field "tx_igldapssoauth_dn".

So if the field "manager" on a record holds the value `CN=Firstname Lastname,OU=Department,DC=example,DC=net` it should connect to the record which has the same value (`CN=Firstname Lastname,OU=Department,DC=example,DC=net`) in the field "tx_igldapssoauth_dn".

Comment: try it with an field of  type = 'passthrough'

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/ColumnsConfig/Type/Passthrough.html

Comment: I have added some more information to my question. My problem ist not saving the value to the field `manger` but connection the field `manager` with the field `tx_igldapssoauth_dn`. I have done some experiments with the `foreign_field` of the field type `inline` https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#foreign-field . But so far no success :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not wise / possible to map this way. Because `tx_igldapssoauth_dn` is not the unique key - `uid` is. I see no problem when using the `fe_users.uid` value.
You can use this uid to get the fe_user Object and from there on get the value you want.

You could just use something similar to:

```
[...]
$yourFrontendUser->getManager()->getTheValueYouWant();
[...]
```

Comment: I added some more information to my question. The field `tx_igldapssoauth_dn` is unique. So basically my question is: Is it really not possible to connect the field `manger` with the field `tx_igldapssoauth_dn`?